# Can this system of polynomial equations be solved in polynomial time?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, linear-algebra, mathematical-programming

I have these **$n$ equations**, with **$n$ variables**. Variables are **first $n$ positive integers**, constants can be any rational number including zero. **Given that there is always a solution**, how do we  find a solution to the system:

\begin{align}
ax^{1}+by^{1}+cz^{1}+\cdots&=k_{1}\\
ax^{2}+by^{2}+cz^{2}+\cdots&=k_{2}\\
ax^{3}+by^{3}+cz^{3}+\cdots&=k_{3}
\end{align}
so on ... till
$$ax^{n}+by^{n}+cz^{n}+\cdots=k_{n}$$

for variables $x,y,z\in \{1,2\ldots, n\}$.

The value of constants $a$,$b$,$c$... remain same in all these equations.

And these constants can also be equal to each other. For e.g: $a = b$ so that values of $x$ and $y$ can become interchangeable. In such cases one working solution is suffice.

Can we find a solution or determine none exist in polynomial time?

---

**Edit: For the sake of clarity here is a simple example.**

If $n=3$, I know $x,y,z$ can only take 1, 2 or 3 as their values. So if I have $x + y + z = 9$, I clearly know that $x, y$ and $z$ are all 3. But if I have $x + y + z = 6$, I don't know whether they are $2,2,2$ or $1,2,3$. Then I can make use of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 14$. Then I will know they are $1,2,3$.

Comment: Have you looked at solution techniques for solving [Diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation)? Would those work for your situation, or would you need something better? Of course, you want 'the best', but the best you can afford is usually 'good enough'.

Comment: @Discretelizard I'm still a noob. Aren't Diophantine equation solving NP complete. I was looking for something P. Because I have extra data, the solution set is not any integer but only first n positive integers. And I have n equations. Even if I did not know they were integers I could still solve them, its just that I have been given with extra information, and I am wondering how can I make use of it and accomplish this in P time.

Comment: Yes, solving Diophantine equations is hard in general, undecidable even. But there are heuristic approaches that might work for your case. I think the question whether this specific case is polynomial time solvable is more focused than your current question. It also allows for a 'no' answer.

Comment: You can try Grobner bases. See for example https://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/cbms.pdf.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus is solving Grobner bases possible in polynomial time?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus if no, then all the effort is wasted, because I can solve this in np time very easily using backtracking.

Comment: In general, finding Grobner basis solutions are not going to be polynomial. However, I'd suggest SAT/SMT solvers here, since the solution space is discrete.

Comment: But as far as I understand Grobner, it solves even more generalized version of my question. Mine is very specific question. We have the same constants. We have n equations, and solution set is integers limited from 1 to n. I have a great suspicion that it can be solved in p-time, but may be I am wrong, even with all these specifications we can't get solution in p-time

Answer (score 3):

Let us denote the unknowns by $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, and the coefficients by $c_1,\ldots,c_n$. For a polynomial $P(x)$, we denote
$$
[P(x)] = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i P(x_i).
$$
We are given the values of $[1],[x],\ldots,[x^n]$, from which we can calculate $[P(x)]$ for every polynomial of degree at most $n$. In particular, we can compute, for each $j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, the value
$$
\left[ \prod_{k \neq j} \frac{x-k}{j-k} \right] = \sum_{i\colon x_i=j} c_i.
$$
To complete the solution, we need to solve several SUBSET-SUM instances, which possibly interact.

Conversely, we can *encode* SUBSET-SUM using your equations. Given a set of positive coefficients $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ summing to $C$ and a target $S$, we encode a solution using $\{1,2\}$-valued variables (where $1$ represents a value in the subset summing to $S$), and can compute $[x^k] = S + (C-S)2^k$. These numbers satisfy
$$
[x^k(x-1)(x-2)] = [x^{k+2}-3x^{k+1}+2x^k] = \\
(S + (C-S)2^{k+2}) - 3(S+(C-S)2^{k+1}) + 2(S+(C-S)2^k) = \\
(1-3+2)S + (4-6+2)(C-S)2^k = 0.
$$
Therefore the argument above shows that every $\{1,\ldots,n\}$-valued solution is actually $\{1,2\}$-valued. Therefore a solution to your problem exists if and only if the SUBSET-SUM instance is a Yes instance.

When all coefficients $c_i$ are equal, the argument above allows us to calculate directly the number of $x_i$'s equal to $j$. Let us take your example: $[1] = 3$, $[x] = 6$ and $[x^2] = 14$. Denoting by $y_j$ the number of $x_i$'s equal to $j$, we compute
$$
\begin{align*}
y_1 &= \left[ \frac{(x-2)(x-3)}{(1-2)(1-3)} \right] = \frac{[x^2-5x+6]}{2} = \frac{14-5\cdot6+6\cdot3}{2} = 1, \\
y_2 &= \left[ \frac{(x-1)(x-3)}{(2-1)(2-3)} \right] = [-x^2+4x-3] =
-14+4\cdot6-3\cdot3 = 1, \\
y_3 &= \left[ \frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{(3-1)(3-2)} \right] = \frac{[x^2-3x+2]}{2} =
\frac{14-3\cdot6+2\cdot3}{2} = 1.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Hey, I think your approach gives the number of variables which have j value. The problem with this is, we cannot directly assign the value to a variable. For E.g if x +y - z = 0, the answer would still be same, there would be one 1, one 2 and one 3. But the value 3 does not get assigned to z, instead I only know that there is a variable whose value is 3. If n gets sufficiently large and if an equation has all the n values but different coefficients it just becomes useless

Comment: I have to disagree. My method gives, for each $j$, the sum of coefficients of variables equal to $j$. Whether this is helpful or not, is another matter.

Comment: Exaclty, but that is not the question, we need to assign the values to variables, that was the goal, but here we will get the frequency of a value in an equation.

Comment: Well, you'll have to take it from there, I'm afraid.

Comment: That's all right, but what I said was correct right? we only get the frequencies of the value. The math you have used is quite complicated, I'm an utter noob.

Comment: In my answer I explain why it might be hard to proceed from that point, since deciding whether a solution exists is NP-complete. In particular cases (for example, small integer coefficients or many equal coefficients) you might be able to proceed somehow.

Comment: The solution will always exist for sure, Thanks for all the effort man.

Answer (score -1):

My algorithm is not an exact one but actually an approximation algorithm.

**Algorithm**

1. Define three matrices

$$
X = 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
 x & y & z & \cdots \\
 x^2 & y^2 & z^2 & \cdots \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
 x^n & y^n & z^n & \cdots
\end{matrix}
\right]_{n \times n}
$$

$$
C = 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
 a \\
 b \\
 c \\
 \vdots
\end{matrix}
\right]_{ n \times 1}
$$

$$
K = 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
 k_1 \\
 k_2 \\
 k_3 \\
 \vdots
\end{matrix}
\right]_{ n \times 1}
$$

We can see that $X \cdot C = K$

2. Find the Inverse Matrix for C. (Yes, inverse of a column matrix)
   $$
   C^{-1} = \frac{C^T}{C_{sq}} \\
   C_{sq} = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + \cdots
   $$

$C^{-1}$ satisfies all properties that a normal matrix inverse does
$$
C^{-1} \cdot C = I_{1 \times 1} \\
C \cdot C^{-1} \cdot C = C
$$

3. Now comes the tricky part. Calculate $C^* = C \cdot C^{-1}$. We can now use this to obtain

$$
X \cdot C \cdot C^{-1} = K \cdot C^{-1} \\
X \cdot C^* = K \cdot C^{-1} \\
X = K \cdot C^{-1} \cdot C^{*{-1}}
$$

The tricky part is that $C^*$ is always singular i.e. $|C^*| = 0$. So it does not have a unique inverse, but has many pseudo-inverses. (Refer: [Moore-Penrose Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) ).

So we have to keep searching for all pseudo-inverses of $C^*$ i.e. $C^{*{-1}}$ such that the result $K \cdot C^{-1} \cdot C^{*{-1}}$ we obtain, matches the pattern observed in $X$.

Comment: Oh God, nature is resilient. The whole point was to make the algorithm in polynomial time, but the moment you said "So we have to keep searching for all pseudo-inverses of C∗" The "polynomialness" is gone.

Comment: @RandomPerfectHashFunction this is the best answer yet, thank you so much for the answer and the effort

Comment: @RandomPerfectHashFunction but I still have some concerns, this is generalized solution, but here the solution set is known, the solution can only be from 1 to n, and  it has to be a positive integer. Can we use this data to our advantage while choosing which pseudo inverse we should be checking?

Comment: Searching for all pseudo-inverses can take exponential time.  I don't see any analysis of the running time of this approach; it seems to me this approach might well be even slower than the naive brute-force  search over all possible solutions; I don't see any reason to expect it to be faster.  So I don't see how this is useful.  (Also, this is not an [approximation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm).)